# Collapse all #+RESULTS block present in the current buffer

Tags: org-mode, functions

## The problem

Because the output of some commands is pretty big, I need to collapse their corresponding `#+RESULTS:` block in order to read the important parts (the commands).

## The question

Is there any function that collapses all the `#+RESULTS` blocks present in the current buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(org-babel-result-hide-all)`

Fold all results in the current buffer.